# Como alocar espaço para cada estrutura de um vetor conforme o usuário desejar?

Tags: c

Galera, como faço para alocar uma estrutura sempre que o usuário desejar alocar outra? Como eu faria esse incremento? Estou colocando um código aqui só para vocês entenderem o meu problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* 
SÍNTESE
OBJETIVO: Calcular bônus de funcionário com mais de 10 anos de serviço
ENTRADA: Nome do funcionário, nome do departamento salário, salário e tempo de serviço
SAÍDA: Nome do funcionário, nome do departamento, salário com bônus ou nao, e tempo de serviço, se deseja continuar
*/


#define MAX_FUNCIONARIOS 5
#define MAX_NOME 100


typedef struct{
    char nome[MAX_NOME];
    char nomeDepartamento[MAX_NOME];
    float salario;
    int tempoServico;

}Funcionarios;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {



    int numEstruturas=0, opcao=0;


    do{

        //aloca dados para um vetor de estruturas
        func = (Funcionarios*) malloc(1*sizeof(Funcionarios));

        //verifica se a alocacao ocorreu corretamente

        if(!func){
            printf("\nNao foi possivel alocar espaco para esta estrutura!\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        printf("Deseja adicionar outra estrutura: (1) ou (2)-sair");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);

        if(opcao == 1){
            func = (Funcionarios*) realloc(numEstruturas*sizeof(Funcionarios));
        }else{
            break;
        }

    }while(opcao==1&&n<MAX_FUNCIONARIOS);




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Precisa de usar um vetor ou uma lista de funcionarios e ir acrescentando funcionarios. Mas tanto para uma solução como outra ainda falta muita coisa no seu código. Sugiro que comece as suas buscas por ai.

Comment: É só um exemplo. Eu só queria saber se está correta a maneira em que estou realocando os dados ou se estou pelo menos perto.

Comment: A realocação com o `realloc` fará sentido se tiver um vetor de funcionários que quer ir aumentando à medida que insere. Nesse sentido sim será esse o caminho, assumindo que o `func` irá ser o vetor de funcionários. No entanto a realocação tem de ser com um tamanho maior de 1 em 1, e ainda falta guardar o elemento na posição correta.

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo.

Comment: Mas a pergunta da forma que está feita não ficou clara pois dá a ideia que pretende alocar usuários soltos sem estarem associados a nenhuma estrutura de dados, quer seja lista ou vetor. Se o objetivo alocar usuarios num  vetor e ir aumentando com `realloc` pode reajustar a pergunta que eu mesmo a responderei

Comment: Ah, sim. Era isso mesmo. Eu acabei me esquecendo desse detalhe. Realmente, eu quero alocar os usuários num vetor e ir aumentando com realloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ir modificando o tamanho do vetor consoante o que o usuário desejar precisa de utilizar [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) como já está a utilizar, mas tem de ir aumentando o tamanho a cada realocação, que não está a fazer.

O mais natural, e assim como mostra a documentação é começar o vetor com `NULL` evitando ter de usar `malloc` no primeiro caso e até testar se é o primeiro caso. Isto não causa nenhum problema pois o `realloc` comporta-se como um `malloc` se o vetor antigo for `NULL`.

Citando a documentação:

> In case that `ptr` is a null pointer, the function behaves like `malloc`, assigning a new block of `size` bytes and returning a pointer to its beginning.

Em tradução livre

> No caso de `ptr` ser um ponteiro nulo a função comporta-se como um `malloc`, atribuindo um novo bloco de `size` bytes e retornando um ponteiro para o seu inicio.

No seu código aplicando estas ideias teria:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numEstruturas = 0, opcao = 0;
    Funcionarios *func = NULL; //vetor agora iniciado com NULL e fora do loop

    do {
        printf("Deseja adicionar outra estrutura: (1) ou (2)-sair");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);

        if(opcao == 1) {
            //realoca, passando o vetor antigo e o novo tamanho
            func = realloc(func, ++numEstruturas * sizeof(Funcionarios));

            //teste se falhou a realocação agora movido para aqui
            if(!func) { 
                printf("\nNao foi possivel alocar espaco para esta estrutura!\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    } while(opcao == 1 && numEstruturas < MAX_FUNCIONARIOS);

    return 0;
}
```

A instrução mais importante desde código é mesmo o `realloc` e veja como está diferente do que tinha, que até lhe faltava um parametro:

```
func = realloc(func, ++numEstruturas * sizeof(Funcionarios));
//              ^        ^-- numero de estruturas já aumentado para ser mais 1
//              |-- vetor antigo
```

Também retirei o `else { break; }` pois caso o usuário escolha outro valor que não o `1` a própria condição do `while` já o irá terminar.

Comment: Isso vai me ajudar muito na prova que farei amanhã. Muito obrigado, Isac.